# I need a plug-in for Wordpress which will allow to our visitors to see our KML file which includes links to images

Tags: plugins, kml

I have KML file which includes links to stored images at our server

http://tlv-ftp.imagesatintl.com/catalogue/ImageSat/AGAPE_B_ImageSat.kml

If you have Google Earth you will see after DL this file number of polygons and by clicking on camera icon on each polygon you will have an option to preview overlay - preview image over Google Earth.

I installed WP flexible map plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-flexible-map/) and when I choose the preview option the image downloaded and opened in Google earth as a polygon without an image.

Does anyone have other suggestion, other plug-in or maybe someone can develop a new one

Thanks a lot
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Instead to use a plugin(WP) you can show your KML directly with google earth plugin on your website.

Follows the documentation for this:

https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/kml

You just need to know a bit of javascript and html. It must be easy to integrate with any CMS like WP.